# Bad query and url not working in Laravel 10.28

Tags: laravel-10

Hello everyone? I have a strange error under Laravel 10.28 that I don't understand.
This is my Route : `Route::get('notes/rattrapage',[NotesController::class,'rattrapage'])->name('notes.rattrapage');`

The controller method :

```
public function rattrapage()
    {
        $filieres = Filiere::with('classes')->where('ecole_id',Auth::user()->ecole_id)->get();
        return view('notes.rattrapage', compact('filieres'));
    }
```

When i call the Route like this : `<li><a href="{{route('notes.rattrapage')}}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Rattrapage</a></li>`

I get error message 404 : [image: first error]

[image: Second error]

I have tried :
`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan route:clear`
and `composer update` but the error remains

Comment: You probably have another route declared for `/notes/{id}` or similar that takes precedence over your `notes.rattrapage` route. Change the order of those routes or use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) on the other route

Comment: You are right. That was the problem. Thank you so much.